# Undefined layerGroup() when unit testing leaflet with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, leaflet

I'm trying to test if my `MyCustomMap` is calling my `MapController` and creating a new leaflet map component.

However `MapController` is setting `_mapGroup` as `undefined` on `MyCustomMap` component and it should be `L.layerGroup()` (not `undefined`).

I already tried to mock `MapController` and `leaflet` in different ways, but `_mapGroup` still being `undefined`. What is wrong? How can I solve this?

**My MyCustomMap test file (custom-map.test.js):**

```
import MyCustomMap from './custom-map';
import initialMapOptions from './map-options';
import MapController from './map-controller';

const mapCreateGroupMock = jest.fn(),
  mapAddGroupToMap = jest.fn();

let myMap = null,
  mapController = null;

beforeAll(() => {
  const mapOptions = initialMapOptions();
  mapController = {
    createGroup: mapCreateGroupMock,
    addGroupToMap: mapAddGroupToMap
  };
  myMap = new MyCustomMap(mapController, mapOptions);
});

describe('My custom map', () => {
  it(`should call MapController and create a new leaflet map component`, () => {
    expect(mapCreateGroupMock).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mapAddGroupToMap).toBeCalledTimes(1);    
    expect(myMap._mapGroup).not.toBeNull();     // -> here is failing because myMap._mapGroup is undefined and shouldn't be
  });
});
```

**My MapController (map-controller.js):**

```
import L from 'leaflet';

class MapController {
  constructor(container, configuration) {
    this._map = new L.Map(container, { zoomControl: false, minZoom: this._minZoom });
    this._container = document.getElementById(container);

    //more code here ...
  }

  createGroup() {
    return L.layerGroup();
  }


  addGroupToMap(group) {
    this._map.addLayer(group);
  }

  //more code here ...
}

export default MapController;
```

**My MyCustomMap component (custom-map.js):**

```
class MyCustomMap {
  constructor(mapController, configuration) {
    this._mapController = mapController;
    this._configuration = configuration;

    this._mapGroup = this._mapController.createGroup();
    this._mapController.addGroupToMap(this._mapGroup);

    //more code here ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! My `mapCreateGroupMock` was simply returning an empty function and I needed to simulate a return value. So I:

- mocked that value;
- perform a `mockClear()` on my mock functions;
- did every that steps on `beforeEach()`;
- and changed my `myMap._mapGroup` assert to `.toBeTruthy()` to check if is not undefined and not null.

Now it work as expected.

**Final changes on MyCustomMap test file (custom-map.test.js):**

```
import MyCustomMap from './custom-map';
import initialMapOptions from './map-options';

const mapCreateGroupMock = jest.fn(),
  mapAddGroupToMap = jest.fn(),
  mapOptions = initialMapOptions();  

let myMap = null,
  mapController = null;

describe('My custom map', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mapCreateGroupMock.mockClear();
    mapAddGroupToMap.mockClear();

    const addLayerMock = jest.fn(),
      mapGroup = {
        addLayer: addLayerMock
      };
    mapCreateGroupMock.mockReturnValueOnce(mapGroup);

    mapController = {
      createGroup: mapCreateGroupMock,
      addGroupToMap: mapAddGroupToMap
    };
    myMap = new MyCustomMap(mapController, mapOptions);
  });

  it(`should call MapController and create a new leaflet map component`, () => {
    expect(mapCreateGroupMock).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mapAddGroupToMap).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(myMap._mapGroup).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```